# Unusual error when installing cuda inside a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running Docker 18 CE on an Ubuntu 18.04 OS. The base image of my docker is Ubuntu 18.04 as well. I am trying to make a custom docker image where I can also run and use nvidia and cuda. I get an unusual issue only when I am installing cuda.

This is the code to get the executable.

```
RUN wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run RUN chmod +x cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run 
RUN ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run
```

When docker starts installing, specifically it reaches this point

```
Step 16/33 : RUN ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run
 ---> Running in dcca0c9973cc
The command line turns completely blank. I dont see an error message, or logs for the process as you usually do. It's just pitch black. I've let it run for hours and there is no response.
```

My Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
 build-essential \
 curl \
 apt-utils \
 python \
 python-dev \
 python-pip \
 python3 \
 python3-dev \
 python3-pip \
 swig \
 unzip \
 sox \
 libsox-dev \
 python-pyaudio \
 git \
 wget \
 silversearcher-ag \
 ranger \
 ffmpeg \
 python3-levenshtein \
 python-numpy \
 libcurl3-dev  \
 ca-certificates \
 gcc-6 \
 g++-6 \
 libsox-fmt-mp3 \
 htop \
 nano \
 cmake \
 zlib1g-dev \
 libbz2-dev \
 liblzma-dev \
 locales \
 pkg-config \
 libsox-dev \
 freeglut3-dev \
 libx11-dev \
 libxmu-dev \
 libxi-dev \
 libglu1-mesa \
 libglu1-mesa-dev \
 dpkg

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install keyboard-configuration

WORKDIR /home/setup/

RUN wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.15.0/bazel-0.15.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
RUN chmod +x bazel-0.15.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
RUN ./bazel-0.15.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
RUN rm bazel-0.15.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh


# Install NVIDIA

#RUN sudo echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
#RUN sudo echo "options nouveau modeset=0" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf

#RUN add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install nvidia-driver-390 -y

# Install Python specific packages

RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip wheel

RUN pip3 install absl-py==0.9.0 \
astor==0.8.1 \
attrdict==2.0.1 \
audioread==2.1.8 \
cffi==1.13.2 \
cycler==0.10.0 \
Cython==0.29.14 \
decorator==4.4.1 \
deepspeech==0.4.1 \
gast==0.3.3 \
grpcio==1.26.0 \
h5py==2.10.0 \
joblib==0.14.1 \
Keras-Applications==1.0.8 \
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0 \
kiwisolver==1.1.0 \
librosa==0.7.2 \
llvmlite==0.31.0 \
Markdown==3.1.1 \
matplotlib==3.1.2 \
numba==0.47.0 \
numexpr==2.7.1 \
numpy==1.18.1 \
pandas==0.25.3 \
progressbar==2.5 \
protobuf==3.11.2 \
pycparser==2.19 \
pydub==0.23.1 \
pyparsing==2.4.6 \
python-dateutil==2.8.1 \
python-Levenshtein==0.12.0 \
python-speech-features==0.6 \
pytz==2019.3 \
resampy==0.2.2 \
scikit-learn==0.22.1 \
scipy==1.4.1 \
six==1.14.0 \
SoundFile==0.10.3.post1 \
tables==3.6.1 \
tensorboard==1.12 \
tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0 \
Werkzeug==0.16.0

## Install Cuda

RUN wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run RUN chmod +x cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run 
RUN ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
#RUN rm cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run

## Install cudnn

RUN wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0ffjf1j0bftrq9/cudnn-9.2-linux-x64-v7.2.1.38.tgz?dl=1 -O cudnn-9.2-linux-x64-v7.2.1.38.tgz
RUN tar -xzvf cudnn-9.2-linux-x64-v7.2.1.38.tgz
RUN cp -P cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda-9.0/include
RUN cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/
RUN chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudnn*

RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/


ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

Comment: Maybe you could add options like "--verbose" to get more output messages, or "--silent" that could do stuff like accepting EULA, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Blank line appears due to `-silent` option absence in your `Dockerfile`. This leads cuda installer to wait for EULA acceptance.
It seems you've lost endline and also filename is mismatched

```
RUN wget -q https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run -O cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
RUN chmod +x cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
RUN ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run --silent
```